# Entity Framework returns zero results

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I created a database with entity framwork code first and seeded 4 columns in a table (see Screenshot).
now i want to retrieve all contacts from the contacts table but recieve zero results.
If i execute the generated sql from ef via management studio (also in the screenshot) it works fine.
I wrote some test codebut the connection seems also fine.
I don't know where to look anymore.

```
  public class ContactDataService : IContactDataService
{
    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAll()
    {
     using (var ctx = new ContactOrganizerDbContext())
        {

            List<Contact> contacts = ctx.Contacts.AsNoTracking().ToList();
            //returns true
            bool isValid = ctx.Database.Exists();
            //returns also true
            bool canOpenClose = canConnectionOpenedAndClosed(ctx);
            return contacts;
        }
    }

    private bool canConnectionOpenedAndClosed(ContactOrganizerDbContext ctx)
    {
        try
        {
            ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
            ctx.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

//C# class

```
    public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post definitions for both C# class and its related DB table for Contact entity?

Comment: Are you connected to correct database? check your connection string I guess you're on another instance/database

Comment: You need to check the entity connection string to make sure it is correct.  Also Entity uses a EDMX file to map the database to the classes in c#.  If the EDMX file is not correct you will not get any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay somehow entityframework created the same database on two different servers.
So Arman Ebrahimpour and  jdweng were right, i was looking at the wrong database.